# Tell the truth Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

There are three people (Ajay, Bhuvi and Chandu), one of them is a Gun, one a missile, and one a robot. The Gun always tells the truth, the missile always lies, and the robot can either lie or tell the truth.

Statements :

Ajay : Chandu is a missile.

Bhuvi : Ajay is a Gun.

Chandu : I am the robot.

Find out the Gun, the missile and the robot?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the:

> Ajay is Gun
> Bhuvi is Robot and
> Chandu is missile

As:

> If we take 2nd statement as true then 1st will be true as well as Gun always says truth

2nd case(false case)

> If we take 2nd statement as false that means both Ajay and Bhuvi can be either missile or robot that makes Chandu Gun which is false(3rd stmt is false)